# How do I define an array of objects in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

**I'm new to typescript plz help**

I'm struggling to understand the error message for the below code. I'm just trying to define an array of objects and can't seem to figure out why it's not working?

```
interface FieldClass {
  id: string,
    name: string,
    type: string,
    label: string
}

const fields: FieldClass[] = [{
  id: 'name',
  name: 'input',
  type: 'name',
  label: 'Name',
}, {
  id: 'email',
  name: 'email',
  type: 'email',
  label: 'Email',
}, {
  id: 'password',
  name: 'password',
  type: 'password',
  label: 'Password',
}, , {
  id: 'confirm-password',
  name: 'confirm-password',
  type: 'confirm-password',
  label: 'Confirm password',
}];
```

Error message:

```
Type '({ id: string; name: string; type: string; label: string; } | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'FieldClass[]'.
  Type '{ id: string; name: string; type: string; label: string; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'FieldClass'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'FieldClass'.  TS2322
```

Comment: Looks fine so far. Just fix `, ,` in `fields` and in your interface `id: string;` (notice `;` instead of `,`) and so on.

Comment: @pzaenger Thanks, that was the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a type error here:

```
  label: 'Password',
}, , {
  id: 'confirm-password',
```

Should be with one comma

```
  label: 'Password',
}, {
  id: 'confirm-password',
```

Comment: I knew it was going to be something stupid like that. Thank you